# Standalone attribute error with linearGradient ReactJS component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I use a very simple linearGradient with ReactJS, I get this error in my browser:

> Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `standalone`.
> If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: standalone="false" or standalone={value.toString()}.
> If you used to conditionally omit it with standalone={condition && value}, pass standalone={condition ? value : undefined} instead.
> linearGradient

Yet I really feel that my values match [TypeScript's requirements](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L2600):

```
<linearGradient
  id="gradient"
  x2="0%"
  y2="100%"
>
  <stop offset="0%" stopColor="red" />
  <stop offset="100%" stopColor="transparent" />
</linearGradient>
```

(the graph displays just fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As illustrated in [`facebook/react` issues 16592](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16592#issuecomment-1049707295), an attribute missing, or with a missing value, could trigger this error message, seen in [`packages/react-dom-bindings/src/shared/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/69728fde0ab2822ba468d9aaaa0c856de3f8547d/packages/react-dom-bindings/src/shared/ReactDOMUnknownPropertyHook.js#L242-L256).

You have that error message, even though your code snippet does not include this attribute. However, React's JSX transpilation could sometimes introduce unexpected attributes based on how you structure your component.

Try isolating the `<linearGradient>` code into its own component and see if the warning persists. If it does not, then there may be a problem in how this component interacts with its parent or children.

Make sure no parent or surrounding SVG elements have an attribute named `standalone` which could inadvertently be passed down as a prop to `linearGradient`.

If nothing else works, you could try explicitly setting the `standalone` attribute to `undefined` to see if that removes the warning.

```
<linearGradient
    id="gradient"
    x2="0%"
    y2="100%"
    standalone={undefined}
>
    <stop offset="0%" stopColor="red" />
    <stop offset="100%" stopColor="transparent" />
</linearGradient>
```